# Order Total Report showing blank while export in CSV or XML in Magento2.2.2

Tags: magento2, reports

Go to `Reports -> Customers -> Order Total Report` apply filter its shows the record as according to filter but when you export the CSV or XML its showing the blank data

Answer (score 0):

Check you server memory or increase memory by php.ini
then run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/pub/static/
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/pub/media/
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/var/
chown -R www-data /var/www/html/yourproject/app/etc/
```